# Getting data from JSON array with Unity C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to use the OpenWeatherMap API in unity C# with JSONUtility and I can't seem to access the "weather" array (specifically "main"), but I can access other information such as "timezone" and "name".

JSON file:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 10.99,
    "lat": 44.34
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 501,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "moderate rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 298.48,
    "feels_like": 298.74,
    "temp_min": 297.56,
    "temp_max": 300.05,
    "pressure": 1015,
    "humidity": 64,
    "sea_level": 1015,
    "grnd_level": 933
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.62,
    "deg": 349,
    "gust": 1.18
  },
  "rain": {
    "1h": 3.16
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 100
  },
  "dt": 1661870592,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2075663,
    "country": "IT",
    "sunrise": 1661834187,
    "sunset": 1661882248
  },
  "timezone": 7200,
  "id": 3163858,
  "name": "Zocca",
  "cod": 200
}
```

In my C# script, I parse the data and I tried to make sure my variable types were accurate to the JSON file.

```
IEnumerator getWeatherInfo()
    {
        var www = new UnityWebRequest("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=" + API_KEY)
        {
            downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer()
        };

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Info = JsonUtility.FromJson<weatherInfo>(www.downloadHandler.text);
        var myData = Info.weather[0].id;

        Debug.Log(myData);
    }
}

[SerializeField]
public class weatherInfo
{
    public Weather[] weather;
    public float timezone;
    public float id;
    public string name;
    public int cod;
}

[SerializeField]
public class Weather
{
    public int id;
    public string main;
    public string description;
    public string icon;
}
```

However, the error I get is [NullReferenceException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XFVA.png) when this line is executed:

```
var myData = Info.weather[0].id;
```

Comment: [JsonUtility don't support nested array](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1322769/parsing-nested-arrays-with-jsonutility.html). A solution is to use [Newton.Json](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/manual/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[SerializeField]` attribute is a Unity specific attribute to serialise, and then usually display, private fields.

> Force Unity to serialize a private field.
>
> When Unity serializes your scripts, it only serializes public fields. If you also want Unity to serialize your private fields you can add the SerializeField attribute to those fields. ([link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)).

What's you need to decorate your classes with is `[Serializable]`. i.e.:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class weatherInfo
{
    public Weather[] weather;
    public float timezone;
    public float id;
    public string name;
    public int cod;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I remember seeing [Serializable] from tutorials online, but I assumed it would work the same as [SerializeField]. After looking at the unity documentation, it all makes sense now. Appreciate the help!